# C - secure execution of system() or exec() with environment variables

Tags: c, linux

I have two strings, both of which can be set by the user, e.g.

```
char *command = "vim $VAR";
char *myVar = "/tmp/something";
```

I want to execute `*command` using `*myVar` for `$VAR`.

I tried concatenating them as an environment variable (e.g. (pseudo-code) `system("VAR=" + *myVar + "; " + *command)`, but the user controls `myVar` so this would be very insecure and buggy.

I considered tokenizing on spaces to directly replace `$var` and passing the results to `exec()`, but it's too awkward to worry about tokenizing shell command arguments correctly.

I think the solution is to emulate `system()` with exec by doing something like `exec("sh", "-c", command, "--argument", "VAR", myVar)`, but I can't see anything in the sh/dash/bash man pages to permit setting environment variables in this way.

**Edit: I just saw execvpe() which has an argument for setting environment variables from key=value strings. Would this be safe to use with untrusted input for the value?**

How do I do this safely?

Comment: What about `execlp("vim", "vim", myVar, (char*)NULL);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform some string replacement on the value of `myVar` — put it inside single quotes, and replace all single quotes (the character `'`) by the four-character string `'\''`. Fiddly but safe if you don't make an implementation mistake. If possible, [use a library that does it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315017).

If your program is single-threaded, I recommend a different solution that doesn't involve fiddly quoting. You talk of setting environment variables… Well, just do it: make `VAR` an environment variable.

```
setenv("VAR", myVar, 1);
system(command);
unsetenv("VAR")
```

I've omitted error checking, and I assume that `VAR` isn't needed elsewhere in your program (if it is, this solution becomes more tedious because you need to remember the old value).

If you want fine control over the environment in which the command runs, you can reimplement `system` on top of `fork`, `execve` (or `execvpe`) and `waitpid`, or on top of `posix_spawn` (or `posix_spawnp`) and `waitpid`. It's more effort but you gain flexibility.

Note that whatever solution you adopt other than doing string replacement to `"vim $VAR"` inside the C program, the command will need to be `vim "$VAR"` and not `vim $VAR`. This is because in shell syntax, `$VAR` means “the value of the variable `VAR`” only if it's inside double quotes — otherwise, `$VAR` means “take the value of `VAR`, split it into words, and expand each word as a file name wildcard pattern”.

Comment: Note that even if you remember the old value of `$VAR`, this is a bad idea in a multi-threaded program, since other threads could access the changed version.  That's why I recommend `fork` and editing the environment only in the child.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point. Why `fork`+`exec*` rather than `posix_spawn`?

Comment: BTW I think you intended to use `setenv`, since `putenv` takes only one parameter of the form `name=value` (you have to mess with the fiddly quoting yourself)

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the string contained in `myVar`; this may mean escaping naughty characters (eg with backslash).

You could use [g_shell_quote](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.40/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html#g-shell-quote) from *Glib*

Answer (score 2):

So as Ben pointed out, `command` is probably loaded at runtime.

I think the best approach is to tokenize `command`, rather than to tokenize `myVar`. You can then find which word in `command` is `$VAR` and replace that with the value of `myVar`. Then you can use `posix_spawnp` as per below.

If you really want `command` to be an arbitrary shell command, then your only option is to escape `myVar` before assigning it to an environment variable. Otherwise the shell will expand spaces and other special characters in it regardless of how you set it.

Third option is to make sure command is `vim "$VAR"` instead of `vim $VAR`. In that case you can assign it to environment using `setenv`, then call `system`, and then unset it after.

Old answer in case `command` is static:

It looks like what you actually want to do is

```
extern char *environ[];
posix_spawnp(NULL, "vim", NULL, NULL, (char*[]){"vim", myVar, NULL}, environ);
wait(NULL);
```

i.e. exec vim directly without any shell, with `myVar` as the first argument.

Comment: This isn't helpful if `"vim $VAR"` is loaded from a (I assume trusted) configuration file.

Answer (score -2):

How about:

1. `fork` (if emulating `system` or `spawn`, skip this if doing `exec`)
2. `setenv("VAR", myVar)` in the fork child
3. `exec` "sh -c " + command

Comment: `exec()` doesn't tokenize arguments.

Comment: @Dietrick: True, this is meant to be a recipe for success, not copy+paste ready code